# Tidy up metadata

Tags: metadata-api, metadata

Are there any apps that can used to analyze the metadata for redundant fields like custom fields which are not used on any layout or VF page which is not referenced anywhere.
Maybe there is some technique or appexchange app to get redundant elements and tidy up metadata.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Natalia,
Here are some ideas:
 1. Field Trip (Free managed package from AppEx - https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N30000003HSXEEA4) - Gives you a way to see which fields actually have data and which is left empty etc.
 2. Easy Describe (Free app from AppEx - https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N300000018leZEAQ) - Help with documenting Objects and fields in your Org.
 3. Digging around - Try running your own queries on tables like Report (using tools like ApexExplorer or SoqlExplorer). This will identify metadata that is not being used.
 4. SnapShot (Paid App - https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N300000016YhyEAE) - Various reports to help identify usage and unnecessary metadata. Also helps with metadata backups and migration. Not cheap but incredibly powerful. Disclaimer: I work for DreamFactory, makers of SnapShot.

Some of these are not directly what you asked for but will give you a good starting point.

Good luck with your optimization efforts. Please let me know what helped and what did not help.

Sridhar